# Is there an easier way to retrieve hard-coded type parameters in subclass implementations?

Tags: java, generics, reflection

Given the following interface:

```
public interface GenericInterface<T> {

    T getValue();
    void setValue(T newVal);
}
```

And the following impl:

```
public class FixedImpl implements GenericInterface<String> {

    String value;

    public FixedImpl(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public void setValue(String newVal) {
        value = newVal;
    }
}
```

I want to be able to determine that in the case of `FixedImpl`, `String.class` is the value for `GenericInterface.T` by interrogating `FixedImpl.class`.

My current idea:

1. Find a method name in `GenericInterface` that returns a `<T>` - in this case, there's `"getValue"`.
2. Go through all the methods declared in `FixedImpl.class` with the same name, and collect all the different return types.
3. The return type farthest from `Object` is my value for `GenericInterface.T`.

But there's a couple of issues with this process:

- It will only work for generic types containing a method that returns `<T>`. You can't safely do the same trick using `setValue(T)`, because method overloading by parameter / arity is possible to do in Java source. It only works for `T getValue()` because overloading by return value isn't (unless I'm mistaken).
- It might have weird interactions with Java 8 default methods, or a generic method implementation in a (still generic) possibly abstract superclass.
- It's kinda kludgey.

Can anybody point me to an easier / more surefire way to get the same information? I can't seem to find one, but I thought I'd ask the superior intellects of the toobs :)

*NB:* If you're wondering why I'd need this, it's because I want to programatically construct mocks of container classes with similar hard-coded type parameters, but POJO values rather than simple Strings.

EDIT: I eventually worked out the following solution (before seeing @stony-zhang's):

```
public static <G> List<Class> getConcreteTypes(Class<? extends G> implClass, Class<G> genericClass) {

    List<Class> concreteTypes = new ArrayList<Class>();

    for (Type type : implClass.getGenericInterfaces()) {

        if (!(type instanceof ParameterizedTypeImpl)) continue;

        ParameterizedTypeImpl parameterizedType = (ParameterizedTypeImpl) type;

        if (parameterizedType.getRawType() != genericClass) continue;

        for (Object arg : parameterizedType.getActualTypeArguments()) {
            if (!(arg instanceof Class))
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Class " + implClass + " not concrete for generic type " + genericClass);
            concreteTypes.add((Class) arg);
        }
    }

    return concreteTypes;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the the class of T by the following way, in the interface add a method getMessageClass(), and in the FixedImpl add the implemented method,

```
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
public Class getMessageClass() {
            int index =0; //In the case, you only have a generic type, so index is 0 to get the first one.
    Type genType = getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
    if (!(genType instanceof ParameterizedType)) {
        return Object.class;
    }
    Type[] params = ((ParameterizedType) genType).getActualTypeArguments();
    if (index >= params.length || index < 0) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Index outof bounds");
    }
    if (!(params[index] instanceof Class)) {
        return Object.class;
    }
    return (Class) params[index];
}
```

In you case, if you have multiple subclass,  to use it, create one abstract class to implement the interface GenericInterface, and then the all subclass extends from the new abstract class,

```
public class abstract abstractImpl<T> implements implements GenericInterface<T> {
        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")

    @Override
      public Class getMessageClass() {
           ...............
      }
}
```

Comment: I accepted your answer because it's right, but I included my own code above, because it's a little more flexible :)

Answer (score 0):

Remember type erasure. At runtime, there is no type information about your generics anymore, unless you specify it yourself. And this is what you should do. Add this to your interface:

```
Class<T> getTypeOfT();
```

And add this to your `FixedImpl`:

```
@Override
public Class<String> getTypeOfT()
{
    return String.class;
}
```

That way, you can always call `getTypeOfT()` on your `GenericInterface<T>` implementations and find out what type you are dealing with.

Comment: If you have a base class implementing this interface (which the original poster did not specify, though this seems like it would be great for code reuse), you could return T.class.

Comment: No, you cannot. `T.class` is not valid, exactly because of type erasure.

Comment: This allows me to get from an instance to the payload class, but not from `FixedImpl.class`. If you can't construct an implementation class without a valid payload (for example), you can never call getTypeOfT(). It also must be written specifically for every generic interface / abstract class, and can't be easily built into a test framework.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you will be able to get reliable result because of [Type Erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html):

> - Replace all type parameters in generic types with their bounds or Object if the type parameters are unbounded. The produced bytecode, therefore, contains only ordinary classes, interfaces, and methods.
> - Insert type casts if necessary to preserve type safety.
> - Generate bridge methods to preserve polymorphism in extended generic types.

Your approach of of using the types of objects returned may at first seem alright, but beyond the issues you have pointed out there is no way (at runtime) to know if `The return type farthest from Object is my value for GenericInterface.T.`

My suggestion would be to use some kind of configuration XML which could be generated at build time based on the java source (using a build tool such as Ant), which would in turn be used to create Mock objects, or you could simply generate the tests based off the source at buildtime.

If you don't mind changing your runtime code for the purposes of testing, Jan Doereenhaus' answer suggests a simple hard-coded mechanism for retrieving the type

**EDIT:**

Consider the scenario:

```
public class FixedImpl implements GenericInterface<SomeClass> {

    @Override
    public SomeClass getValue() {
        return new SomeClass();
    }
}

public class FixedImpl2 extends FixedImpl {

    @Override
    public SomeClass getValue()
    {
        return new SomeSubClass();
    }
}
```

From this example, you can see that the sub class of FixedImpl is able to return a subclass of `T` (which is further down the inheritance hierarchy from `Object`)

Comment: All true, but erasure applies to `GenericInterface`, not to `FixedImpl` which has no type params. I'm interested to know the scenario I haven't thought of in which the furthest type from `Object` is not the correct value?

Comment: Right, I get what you're saying that the furtherst type from Object (FixedImpl2) can return a subclass of SomeClass, but it wouldn't come up if I'm looking for the payload class of FixedImpl itself. Also, as a container rather than just a provider, it's invariant once you provide a value for <T> by marking your class as providing an implementation for GenericInterface<FooClass> rather than parameterizing your class and just implementing GenericInterface<T>.